# Using dynamic_cast in c++

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

I have 4 classes in c++ . Animal is the super class were Snake and Tiger inherit from Animal but also inherit from Dangerous Animal . I have implemented a function to check if Snake or tiger is an instance of DangerousAnimal . However I am finding problems in implemting it in c++

my code is :

```
bool Vet::examine (Animal *someAnimal){

        if(DangerousAnimal* s = dynamic_cast<DangerousAnimal*>(Animal)){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
```

The error is

```
dillu24@dillu24-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/OOP/Lab1$ g++ -std=c++11 -oAnimalWellBeingLauncher AnimalWellBeingLauncher.cpp q1.cpp
q1.cpp: In member function ‘bool Vet::examine(Animal*)’:
q1.cpp:122:64: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
   if(DangerousAnimal* s = dynamic_cast<DangerousAnimal*>(Animal)){
```

Comment: The code, the code, where is the code! Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): Minimal (OK) Complete (!!) Verifiable (!!) Example. Your example is neither complete nor verifiable, and therefore you will need multiple round-trips to get your code to compile.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of `dynamic_cast` is `dynamic_cast<TargetType>(variable)`, so you have to write `dynamic_cast<DangerousAnimal*>(someAnimal)`.

Comment: Lloge it is saying source type is not polymorphic

Comment: @DylanGalea - no, the error message is saying that `Animal` isn't the right kind of argument to `dynamic_cast`; it should be `someAnimal`, as this answer says.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Dylan is reporting the _next_ error, which is due to the classes being defined incorrectly.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - that may well be, but it's not in the question, nor is it at all clear from the code. And, of course, a comment to an answer is not an appropriate place to bring up a new issue.

Comment: @PeteBecker: I concur. But that is what happened, so your comment response was (at best) misplaced.